# Common variable in python abstract class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

I have **abstract_class** which is inherited by **first_concrete_class** and **second_concrete_class**.

I need to have variable **max_height** in **abstract_class** where it is common to concrete classes and can edit shared variable.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty

class abstract_class:
   __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
   max_height = 0

   @abstractmethod
   def setValue(self, height): pass
```

**max_height** is initially set to 0.

```
class first_concrete_class(abstract_class):

   def setValue(self, height): 
      super().max_height = height   # Something like this?
```

`first_concrete_class().setValue(100)` should change value in abstract_class value of **max_height**, not just **max_height** value inherited to **first_concrete_class**.

```
class second_concrete_class(abstract_class):

   def __init__(self): 
       print(super().max_height)   # Something like this?
```

Output should be *100* rather than initial **max_height** value of 0.

Is there a way in python to do this? If possible how can this variable be accessed by external sources since it can not be initiated. (Ex: **abstract_class**.**max_height**)

Comment: Are you sure you understand that `max_height` is a class variable here, not an instance variable?

Comment: With `super().max_height = height` you're setting an instance variable. Use `abstract_class.max_height = height` if you want to set the value on the class itself.

Comment: I could `print(super().max_height)` in concrete classes but can not set `super().max_height= 100` as such. Can't we set class variables? Will it effect all the concrete classes inherited by it?

Comment: @zwer thanks it worked. Is this correct in object oriented manner?

Comment: Also the strange thing is that you're using metaclasses as if it were python2, but you use `super` as if it were python3. Your best option is to explain what are you trying to achieve in the end with that code. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Chathuranga94 - it is, if you need to change a class variable value. When you call `super()` you're still receiving a pointer to the current instance, just without the current override (if there was any) so setting/calling anything returned from `super()` still happens in the instance space.

Comment: @user1685095 Sorry, I am pretty new to python. Original task is that there are machine learning sub_classes. If current sub_class.accuracy is better than current_accuracy, it should replace it. This current_accuracy could be edited by sub_class. These modified values should be visible to sub_class rather than inheriting initial current_accuracy. Simply all the sub_classes should have access to this shared variable to get/set.

Comment: @zwer Got it... Thanks!!!

Comment: @Chathuranga94 Well, if accuracy in subclass is better (whatever that means) you know it at the time of writing the code. If you would redefine accuracy - you would override parent accuracy. So if it worse - just don' t override it. If it's better - override.

Comment: @user1685095 yeah... will use that. Thanks!!!